# How do we fill half rectangle in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

With `\filldraw[color=red] (0,0) rectangle  (5,4)` filling the complete rectangle, how do we fill only first half or first diagonal in rectangle in TikZ

Comment: You draw a second smaller filled rectangle or triangle.

Comment: to have two rectangles with fill and one over just drawing?

Comment: Zarko no. We have only one rectangle and we need to fill only half of it

Comment: i suggest you to compose your rectangle from two of them (with half width or height) ...

Answer (score 9):

That's what `path picture`s are for.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[path picture={\fill[red] (path picture bounding box.south west)
  rectangle (path picture bounding box.east);}] (0,0) rectangle  ++ (5,4);
  \draw[path picture={\fill[red] (path picture bounding box.south west)
  -- (path picture bounding box.north east) |-cycle;}] (6,0) rectangle  ++ (5,4);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, this can be cast into styles, and works for arbitrary shapes, not just rectangles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[fill lower half/.style={path picture={\fill[#1] (path picture bounding box.south west)
  rectangle (path picture bounding box.east);}},
  fill lower right/.style={path picture={\fill[#1] (path picture bounding box.south west)
  -- (path picture bounding box.north east) |-cycle;}}]
  \draw[fill lower half=red] (0,0) rectangle  ++ (5,4);
  \draw[fill lower right=red] (6,0) rectangle  ++ (5,4);
  \node[cloud,draw,fill lower half=blue,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=3cm] 
  at (2.5,-5){};
  \node[cloud,draw,fill lower right=blue,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=3cm] 
  at (8.5,-5){};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[red]    (0,0) rectangle  ++ (5,2);
  \draw         (0,0) rectangle  ++ (5,4);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[blue]   (0,0) -- ++ (5,4) |- cycle;
  \draw         (0,0) rectangle  ++ (5,4);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]